# How do you find out the range of values when dealing with simultaneous equations?

Tags: quadratics

Find the range of value for $k$ for which $kx + y = 3$ meets $x^2 + y^2 = 5$ in two distinct points.

im so stuck can someone give me a clear guide to the correct method and answer, thank you

Comment: $kx+y=3\implies y=3-kx.$ The line and the circumference have two points in common if $x^2+(3-kx)^2=5$ has two different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2=5$$
$$y=3-kx$$

$$x^2+(3-kx)^2=5$$

$$x^2+9+k^2x^2-6kx=5$$
$$(1+k^2)x^2-6kx+4=0$$

Distinct Real roots $\Rightarrow\Delta\gt0$
$$b^2-4ac\gt0$$
where $b=-6k$ , $a=1+k^2$ , $c=4$

$$36k^2-16(1+k^2)>0$$

$$20k^2-16>0$$
$$\Rightarrow |k|\gt\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$$

Comment: where did you get the $36$ from?

Comment: The discriminant is $b^2 - 4ac$ with $b = -6k$, $a = 1 + k^2$, and $c = 4$.

Comment: I understand now thank you very much :D

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Put $y=3-kx$ in the second equation to form a Quadratic Equation in $x$

Each value of $x$ corresponds to the abscissa of the intersection

Do you know how to find the nature of roots of a Quadratic Equation?

Comment: Thank you very much :)   Once i expand the brackets to $x^2 + 4 - 6kx +kx^2 = 0$ i cant seem to be able to find x still :(

Comment: Yes, well sort of

Comment: @Kelly, You need to arrange as $$Ax^2+Bx+C=0$$ Have you heard of discriminant ?

Comment: Yes i understand the discriminant and everything, i dont understand where i plug $x$

Comment: @Kelly,Why do you want "where I plug " $x$?

Comment: I understand now thank you very much, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to draw a picture, it is easy to see that $-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} < k<\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} $

Answer (score 0):

This is a circle with diameter 5 centred at the origin, and a line which is pivoted at y=3. Think of the line as a pendulum sweeping through the plane and intersecting with the circle. Since the pivot is above the top of the circle then during its sweep it will intersect at two distinct points with the circle except when the line becomes tangent to the circle at two points. This is when |k|=2/√5. Note that k is the negative of the slope of the line.